# Unable to restart Ghost: process 1494

Tags: node.js, npm, ghost-blog

I am trying to run the following command on my ghost node instance running ghost

$ service ghost restart

And I keep getting the following:
"$ ghost stop/waiting ghost start/running, process 1494"

The process number changes depending on when I try and do it. I have looked in the logs and cant find anything?
I have tried using sudo, to no effect.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a problem with your control script.  Try just killing the process manually and then issuing a service start:

```
   # kill -9 1494
```

or whatever your process id is at the time